# T-SQL : create trigger to copy new columns from one table to another and increment no

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger to copy newly added rows from one table on a different database but on the same server to another table and increment a column which only exists on the table where the new rows are being added. I'm not sure if the code is accurate and would like any feedback on how it can be improved.

```
CREATE TRIGGER AddReTncyTransStatement 
ON [DBAdmin].[dbo].[ReTncyTransStatement]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [DBAdmin].[dbo].[ReTncyTransStatement]
                ([ORG-CODE], [TNCY-SYS-REF], [TRANS-NO], [PROGRESS-RECID])
        SELECT        
            [ORG-CODE],
            [TNCY-SYS-REF],
            [TRANS-NO],
            [ANALYSIS-CODE] ``,
            (SELECT MAX([PROGRESS-RECID]) 
             FROM [DBAdmin].[dbo].[ReTncyTransStatement]) + 1 AS RECID
        FROM            
            [SQLViewsPro2EOD].[dbo].[RE-TNCY-TRANS]
END;
```

Comment: This query wont work as expected, because you have created a AFTER INSERT trigger on a table and you are trying to insert to the same table inside the trigger again.

Comment: What could I change it to, to fix it? Sorry I've never written a trigger before.

Comment: I have posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that you have a table called `[RE-TNCY-TRANS]` which is in `[SQLViewsPro2EOD]` database and the other table which is `[ReTncyTransStatement]` that resides inside the `[DBAdmin]` database.

I also imagine that you want to insert a record into `[ReTncyTransStatement]` each time a record inserted into `[RE-TNCY-TRANS]`. So to achieve this you need to rewrite your trigger as below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AddReTncyTransStatement
ON [SQLViewsPro2EOD].[dbo].[RE-TNCY-TRANS]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [DBAdmin].[dbo].[ReTncyTransStatement]
    (
        [ORG-CODE],
        [TNCY-SYS-REF],
        [TRANS-NO],
        [PROGRESS-RECID]
    )
    SELECT [ORG-CODE],
           [TNCY-SYS-REF],
           [TRANS-NO],
           ISNULL((
               SELECT MAX([PROGRESS-RECID]) FROM [DBAdmin].[dbo].[ReTncyTransStatement]
           ),0) + 1 AS RECID
    FROM Inserted;
END;
```

**Update**

*Why I used the ISNULL function?*

Because at the first time, there is no record in `[DBAdmin].[dbo].[ReTncyTransStatement]` table, so the `MAX([PROGRESS-RECID])` will be NULL. I used `ISNULL` to handle this situation.

*Why I used the `inserted`?*

According to the Microsoft docs:

> The inserted table stores copies of the affected rows during INSERT
>   and UPDATE statements. During an insert or update transaction, new
>   rows are added to both the inserted table and the trigger table. The
>   rows in the inserted table are copies of the new rows in the trigger
>   table.

Read more here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks Vahid, Spot on with the logic. Can you explain why you used in isnull and why FROM Inserted please?

Comment: @user3306489 I have updated the answer. check it, and mark it as answer if you found it correct and useful.

Comment: Thanks Vahid, Is there anymore set up/dev work I need to do to get this working?

Comment: @user3306489 It works fine, if my aforementioned scenario is correct

Comment: I meant in terms of if it will start running automatically once it is created. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Vahid, I get the error The object 'SQLViewsPro2EOD.dbo.RE-TNCY-TRANS' does not exist or is invalid for this operation. When I try to execute

Comment: @user3306489 check database 'SQLViewsPro2EOD' to find if table with name 'RE-TNCY-TRANS' exists inside it or not?

Comment: Should this trigger be created on that table?

Comment: @user3306489 Every DML triggers created on tables or views. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Sorry Vahid, the PROGRESS-RECID field populated with the same number but incremented once. So the 2000 records inserted have the same number. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @user3306489 how are you inserting that 2000 records? Please post another question, so that we can concentrate on it. Send the new post link here please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56258176/incrementing-record-id-when-insterting-records-using-a-trigger