# Incrementing RECORD_ID When insterting records using a trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using a trigger to insert rows into a table using INSERT statement as below but when doing this the RECORD_ID number increments by 1 digit so all the records inserted have the same number..

This is what i'm using to increment the records from the trigger.

```
, ISNULL((
               SELECT MAX([PROGRESS-RECID]) FROM [DBAdmin].[dbo].[ReTncyTransStatement]
           ),0) + 1 AS [PROGRESS-RECID]
```

This is what i'm using to load the data

```
;WITH TestTrans   (
       [ORG-CODE]
      ,[TNCY-SYS-REF]
      ,[TRANS-NO]
      ,[POSTING-YEAR]
      ,[POSTING-WEEK]
      ,[TRANS-YEAR]
      ,[TRANS-WEEK]
      ,[TRANS-DATE]
      ,[ACCOUNT-TYPE]
      ,[ACCOUNT-CODE]
      ,[COMMENT]
      ,[TRANS-AMT]
      ,[SOURCE]
      ,[CREATED-USER]
      ,[CREATED-DATE]
      ,[CREATED-TIME]
      ,[UPDATED-USER]
      ,[UPDATED-DATE]
      ,[UPDATED-TIME]
      ,[BATCH-NO]
      ,[BATCH-NO-TYPE]
      ,[SUSPENSE-REF]
      ,[REFERENCE]
      ,[MGT-AREA]
      ,[ANALYSIS-CODE]
      ) 
AS (SELECT   
       [ORG-CODE]
      ,[TNCY-SYS-REF]
      ,[TRANS-NO]
      ,[POSTING-YEAR]
      ,[POSTING-WEEK]
      ,[TRANS-YEAR]
      ,[TRANS-WEEK]
      ,[TRANS-DATE]
      ,[ACCOUNT-TYPE]
      ,[ACCOUNT-CODE]
      ,[COMMENT]
      ,[TRANS-AMT]
      ,[SOURCE]
      ,[CREATED-USER]
      ,[CREATED-DATE]
      ,[CREATED-TIME]
      ,[UPDATED-USER]
      ,[UPDATED-DATE]
      ,[UPDATED-TIME]
      ,[BATCH-NO]
      ,[BATCH-NO-TYPE]
      ,[SUSPENSE-REF]
      ,[REFERENCE]
      ,[MGT-AREA]
      ,[ANALYSIS-CODE] from [SQLViewsPro2Live].[dbo].[RE-TNCY-TRANS] where [TRANS-DATE] between '2019-05-16 00:00:00.000' and '2019-05-17 00:00:00.000'
      )    
INSERT INTO [SQLViewsPro2Test].[dbo].[RE-TNCY-TRANS]   
    SELECT 

     [ORG-CODE]
      ,[TNCY-SYS-REF]
      ,[TRANS-NO]
      ,[POSTING-YEAR]
      ,[POSTING-WEEK]
      ,[TRANS-YEAR]
      ,[TRANS-WEEK]
      ,[TRANS-DATE]
      ,[ACCOUNT-TYPE]
      ,[ACCOUNT-CODE]
      ,[COMMENT]
      ,[TRANS-AMT]
      ,[SOURCE]
      ,[CREATED-USER]
      ,[CREATED-DATE]
      ,[CREATED-TIME]
      ,[UPDATED-USER]
      ,[UPDATED-DATE]
      ,[UPDATED-TIME]
      ,[BATCH-NO]
      ,[BATCH-NO-TYPE]
      ,[SUSPENSE-REF]
      ,[REFERENCE]
      ,[MGT-AREA]
      ,[ANALYSIS-CODE]
   FROM TestTrans;  
GO
```

Any fixes appreciated
Thanks,

Full description of problem available here: [T-SQL : create trigger to copy new columns from one table to another and increment no](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56240539/1666800)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question currently isn't really answerable, I'm afraid.  Please see [ask] and [mcve] for some suggestions and guidelines on how you can improve your question, which will increase the likelihood that someone here can help you.  Also, why are you using a `Trigger` to do an insert?

Answer (score 1):

Make PROGRESS-RECID an [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017) column and it will auto-increment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the linked question, you can rewrite your trigger as following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AddReTncyTransStatement
ON [SQLViewsPro2EOD].[dbo].[RE-TNCY-TRANS]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ORG_CODE INT,
            @TNCY_SYS_REF INT,
            @TRANS_NO INT;
    DECLARE C CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR(
    SELECT Inserted.[ORG-CODE],
           Inserted.[TNCY-SYS-REF],
           Inserted.[TRANS-NO]
    FROM Inserted);
    OPEN C;
    FETCH NEXT FROM C
    INTO @ORG_CODE,
         @TNCY_SYS_REF,
         @TRANS_NO;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO [DBAdmin].[dbo].[ReTncyTransStatement]
        (
            [ORG-CODE],
            [TNCY-SYS-REF],
            [TRANS-NO],
            [PROGRESS-RECID]
        )
        SELECT 
               @ORG_CODE,
               @TNCY_SYS_REF,
               @TRANS_NO,
               ISNULL((SELECT MAX([PROGRESS-RECID]) FROM [DBAdmin].[dbo].[ReTncyTransStatement]),0) + 1 AS RECID;

        FETCH NEXT FROM C
        INTO @ORG_CODE,
             @TNCY_SYS_REF,
             @TRANS_NO

    END;
    CLOSE C;
    DEALLOCATE C;

END;
```

**Root of your problem**:

When you use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`(The one outside the trigger), trigger will be called once and the `inserted` table will contain all the records to be inserted. so the query inside the trigger will be run once, furthermore the `SELECT MAX([PROGRESS-RECID])` will be calculated once. This means that if the inserted table contains 10 records, that are being inserted, then `MAX(...)` will be same for all of them!

**How I Solved it:**

Inside the trigger I used `Cursor` to iterate through the all records that are being inserted(For example 10 records), then in each iteration I insert one record to `ReTncyTransStatement` so the `MAX(...)` will be calculated and executed as expected.